# How get data from all pages(tabs) on one specific site (url)

Tags: c#, html, .net, webclient, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get information of listed items on one online market with my C# application. I have specified URL containing filter, so after refresh desired items will show up. Problem is that the shop only shows 10 items per page and there are another 39 pages (can't be changed on the website).
In the URL I can speficy page numbering #p1 and although I change it for example to #p2, source code will show the first ten items. Nothing changed.

Even though Im on #p2 in browser, downloaded sourcecode say this:

```html
<span id="searchResults_start">1</span>
-
<span id="searchResults_end">10</span>
of 
<span id="searchResults_total">383</span>
results
```

I'm using WebClient and now trying HtmlAgilityPack to resolve my thing.

Comment: have you inspected the tags on the second page to make sure that each page doesn't get numbered 1 through 10 on display, even though it represents technically item x+1 through x +10.  I know many a lazy web developer who would have just hardcoded those id's and spans.

Comment: can we share the url you are accessing ?

Comment: I found the issue. Listing of the results on the Shop web site are done via ajax call. So the source code of the original HTML only include the first then items. I have been told that to get data of later pages, I should monitor the network activty of the page. I made it, and I found there desired source code.